# Windows 8: identify and consolidate files

Tags: windows-8, find

Windows 8: How can I output a list by folder of all my MP3 music files which I can import into Excel so I can then select and consolidate in one folder?

I have seen some code which would appear to do this without human intervention but I am worried about apps which might have MP3 files which would then not be able to find them.

Comment: It would be easy to locate all MP3s on your system (using Windows search or `dir` for example), and even automate the consolidation using a batch file, but how would the code know which audio files belong to a program and shouldn't be moved?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `dir *.mp3 /s >list` at the command prompt in root and open `list` with Excel, then create a batch file to move as appropriate.